# Chrome Dev Editor (CDE) Default Shortcut Key Bindings?

Tags: polymer, ace-editor, chrome-dev-editor

I am having lots of fun playing with the new CDE, BUT, I have not been able to find much documentation on it.

Does anyone know the default shortcut key bindings? And secret commands?

I understand it is based off of the Ace Editor, but it seems to not follow the default key bindings:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts

The one I need NOW is Find and Replace, it is not CtrlR, which appears to be RUN.

I know creating and maintaining documentation is dull, but at some point a simple link to basic features would be nice. Good thing to do while is super cold out right now (Canada).

Comment: CTRL + H is Find and replace, sadly I don't know where to find a full shortcut documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complicated...

1. A cross-OS way to get to Replace in CDE is to press `Ctrl-F` (`Command-F` on a Mac) twice. Every subsequent press will alternate between Find and Replace. That's the default Ace behavior, as can be seen it its own [proof-of-concept "Ace kitchen sink" page](http://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html).
2. I'm not even sure whether `Ctrl-R` is up-to-date: I've checked a couple of other IDEs that use Ace, and it doesn't work there (Ace's own Cloud9, Zed, ...).
3. `Ctrl-H` works on everything except Mac. Unfortunately, on a Mac, its equivalent `Command-H` is reserved by the system and hides the current window.
4. I've filed a bug against Chrome Dev Editor to do something about it: https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/issues/3803.
5. Currently, there is no way to see the shortcut bindings in CDE: it's bad, and we (the CDE team) are going to fix that sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

CDE uses the ACE editor.  Here are the default key bindings for it:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts